# Cannot connect icecream (icecc) on Fedora

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, fedora, distributed-computing

I can't manage to get an [icecc](https://github.com/icecc/icecream) daemon to connect to the local icecc-scheduler from any machine running Fedora 20.

I've had no issues setting this up on 5 different Ubuntu 14.04 machines, and each can run the scheduler with no issue. In fact, it appears to work out of the box with no additional config on Ubuntu - simple install and play.

In those cases on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install icecc
sudo service iceccd start
```

And on one of the machines

```
sudo service icecc-scheduler start
```

Then simply setting the path and building like so

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/icecc/bin:$PATH
make -j16
```

This is all that is needed to get the distributed compile working on Ubuntu as far as I can see.

On Fedora installing and starting I use

```
sudo yum install icecream.x86_64
sudo systemctl start iceccd
```

And compiling with

```
export PATH=/usr/libexec/icecc/bin:$PATH
make -j16
```

This doesn't distribute the compile.
The icemon utility on the scheduler does not show any evidence of the fedora machine either and running a status on the iceccd service gives this error:

```
Jul 21 09:44:08 Fedora20 iceccd[4642]: [4642] 09:44:08: scheduler not yet found.
```

So far the only thing I've tried that might have been the issue is opening up the ports that the readme provides by adding them to the Zones->Ports part of Firewall Configuration , but this hasn't helped.

Maybe there is something I need to do on the Ubuntu schedular and daemons? Has anyone else had any luck with setting up icecream on Fedora 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other future devs who might come here from google -

To get icecc working I edited the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/icecc/iceccd-wrapper` file by adding two arguments to the iceccd command.

```
-s <schedular> -m <number of jobs>
```

Then when running the following command

```
sudo systemctl start iceccd
```

The daemon starts up and is seen by the scheduler.

Remember the ports also need to be open!

Answer (score 2):

Instead to editing either `/usr/lib/systemd/system/icecc/iceccd-wrapper` (like proposed by [foips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090266/foips)) or `/usr/lib/systemd/system/iceccd.service` itself, I found it more convenient to modify global icecream settings file `/etc/sysconfig/icecream` and set

```
# If the daemon can't find the scheduler by broadcast (e.g. because
# of a firewall) you can specify it.
#
ICECREAM_SCHEDULER_HOST="<scheduler>"
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 with ICECC 1.3.1 the config file is `/etc/icecc/icecc.conf` and the setting is called `ICECC_SCHEDULER_HOST`. You need to put the scheduler IP there.